# Why is my localhost not updating anymore when I change the source files?

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, updating

When I edit any of the source files for a project I'm working on, none of it is updating to the localhost. When I check on the developer tools in Chrome none of my edits show up. Just old versions of the files I had.

I've tried a couple things already:

- I refreshed the page on Chrome. (even with ctrl+f5 to prevent it fromloading from cache)
- I restarted Chrome entirely.
- I cleared my cache in Chrome.
- I restarted Apache.
- I used Firefox instead of Chrome.

None of these things seemed to have done anything. the page doesn't seem to see any of the changes I make to the source files.

I've checked if I got the right path a dozen times.
It doesn't update any file, it's not just one of them.
The files are actually being saved. If I open the files in a different app I see the edited version.
I tried if it would see changed I made on a different file. That also didn't work.

Does anyone know what could be going on here and how I would fix it?

Comment: Maybe you are checking a web server that has a different document root?? If not, this just seems like a joke to me XD

Comment: Still don't know what was going on but I went off of my pc for a while, came back and turned my pc on again, and all files in PhpStorm were back to what the localhost saw them as and everything worked fine afterwards.

Comment: Probably cache. Somehow

Comment: Even for me bro. But when I rename the source file name it works fine. How did you solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Apache error logs /var/log/apache2/error.log;
There may be something going wrong with some Apache module (PHP, XDebug, HTTP module, etc.).

Also check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184722/apache-not-reading-changes-to-php-files) similar question